# Do I need security rules on my Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

It is unclear whether or not to set security rules for database.

Is it enough to just let in just authenticated users? Do I need more complicated things? I have android app, and do all validations and updates inside app.

The video from IO says that there is possibility that someone can get all your data if he knew your app ID. So if user is authenticated and have app ID and somehow build web app he can get data too? I mean if using simple rules.

I`m asking for risks when building just android app and using simple rules (auth is on).

Comment: Don't trust clients. Even if they are authenticated they will be able to construct their own posts to the DB via simple tooling. Each user should have the rules set with access to only the data you want them to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ok for you if any user could edit/create/delete any data in your Firebase database? If this is not ok, you need security rules (you probably need them)

Firebase's security rules are really powerful and easy to use, I suggest you take a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Answer (score 0):

You need user id or role specific rules, otherwise somebody for example can easily wipe out your all data, or easily manipulate anything.